# Understanding the sizes prop for images in Next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm trying to wrap my head around the sizes prop referenced [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#sizes).

I'm serving images from a CDN, so they're external. All of the images have different widths and heights, but I style them with tailwind to have max-widths and an aspect ratio.

For example, I have a container that is set to `md:max-w-6xl` (1152px in tailwind). This is the code I currently have:

```
<div className=' md:max-w-6xl mx-auto mb-24 '>
  <div className='relative w-full aspect-w-4 aspect-h-3  mx-auto'>
    <Image
      priority={true}
      fill={true}
      className='object-cover object-center'
      src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMG_PREFIX}${coverImage}`}
      alt={"yadayada"}
      placeholder='blur'
      blurDataURL={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMG_PREFIX}${coverImage}`}
      quality={75}
    />
  </div>
<div className=' md:max-w-6xl mx-auto mb-24 '>
```

Would this be the correct code to use for the sizes prop:
`sizes='(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1152px) 50vw, 33vw'`?

Then, on my main blog feed, the cover photos of posts get pushed down into different column widths as new ones are added. They all sit in a container with `max-w-md md:max-w-3xl xl:max-w-6xl mx-auto`:

[image: Most recent posts]
[image: Older posts]

I have no clue how to even begin figuring out the breakpoints for that.

- The top posts have an aspect ratio of 4x3 with `grid grid-cols-1  sm:grid-cols-2`
- The secondary posts have an AR of 3x4 with `grid grid-cols-2  sm:grid-cols-4`
- The oldest posts are flexed with `sm:w-2/5 2xl:w-2/5`

I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time wrapping my brain around this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.